# grails refresh a google chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

I have a page X in my grails app which has a button to display a chart. It will call a controller with a domain object's id and the chart gets rendered in another page. Till here everything is clear to me.

However I have to **reload** the rendered chart page every 20 seconds. My website is a private one with few admin users only. So I decided to use simple javascript polling to do the refresh.
This is the snippet in the chart `gsp` page that I want to reload every 20 seconds. Maybe using javascript `setInterval`.
`<g:render id="chart" template="/building/${chartTemplate}" model="${model}"></g:render>`

My controller requires a sensor id to be passed in when creating the chart, can I use the java script to do that? If so, how can I get it to the javascript function from the controller which initially redirected it here.

This is my GSP template which renders the chart.

```
<div id="linechart"></div>
<gvisualization:lineCoreChart dynamicLoading="${true}" elementId="linechart" title="${title}" 
 width="${750}" height="${450}" columns="${columns}" data="${data}"/>
```

Some weird javascript I have used, but not working.

```
<input type="text" id="sensorid" disabled="disabled" value="${sid }"/>
            <g:javascript>
                var int=self.setInterval("chart()",1000);
                var sensid;
                function chart(){
                    var d=new Date();
                    var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
                    sensid = document.getElementById("sensorid").value;
                }
                ${remoteFunction(controller:"building", action:"createChart", params:"'sid=' + sensid")}
            </g:javascript>
```

Is there a way in which the javascript can reload the page. Full page reload is also fine. I have near zero knowledge of javascript so any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention reloading the entire page is acceptable, then two easy ways would be:

1) Include a META REFRESH tag in your GSP. Eg:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

This is quite convenient, especially if you don't need to change the params (eg if the controller handles anything such as curent date/time used to update chart, etc).

2) Either via Javascript "setTimeout" or a specific action, call a reload (or "history.go(0)", or "window.location.href=window.location.href").

Eg for a button action to test it:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload this page" onClick="window.location.reload();">
```

or to do it automatically every 5 seconds, such as in this (extremely stripped down, so yes I've skipped things such as head, body and other tags..) HTML example:

```
<script>
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",5000);
</script>

Hello world.
```

This gives you more control over exactly what you call, and could easily be modified to redirect to a different controller, same controller with new params, etc.

Comment: That worked! Now I am getting bit more ambitious...:) Is it easy to reload only part of the page? How do I call the controller from java script with the same set of params? Would love to know that.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "easy". ;) Looking at that plugin's doc page it appears it does support the capabilities needed to do more fun Javascript with it, but since you mention you're not well-versed in JS that would make it tougher. On the "Call with different params" part, though, if you use the window.location.href function mentioned above you can direct it to the URL of your choosing (eg window.location.href = "/mycontroller?param1=foo&param2=bar";)

Comment: Ok. I actually want use the same set of params. My controller takes care of dates etc. I pass in an id to the view, the js should get this param(how?) and pass it back on the call to the controller. But anyway looks like this will reload the whole page...:(

Comment: Yeah, the window.location calls are reloads, so the AJAX methods combined with some fancier JS would be what you'd be looking for. Essentially you'd make a call to another controller that returns nothing but the visualization, then replace the content inside the page with that. Someone using the plugin may already have a good example of that, it's just likely to be a big ol' bunch of Javascript. Would definitely recommend posing that as a separate question so someone with those skills may see it.